# Can't deserialise AWS EventBridge Pipe Protobuf events from self-managed Kafka

Tags: amazon-web-services, protocol-buffers, aws-event-bridge

I've configured a [EventBridge Pipe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes.html) to consume events from a [self-managed Kafka](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes-kafka.html) and then forward them to a Step Function.

The topic we are consuming from has Protobuf messages, so the events in the Pipe look like this:

```json
[
  {
    "topic": "<REDUCTED>",
    "partition": 0,
    "offset": 226,
    "timestamp": 1694180898000,
    "timestampType": "CREATE_TIME",
    "key": "ABCDVE1BTi0yMDIzLTA5LTA3",
    "value": "AAAAFVwAChJ .......... pZGVudCBub24gAoABAQ==",
    "headers": [],
    "bootstrapServers": "smk://<REDUCTED>",
    "eventSource": "SelfManagedKafka",
    "eventSourceKey": "<REDUCTED>"
  }
]
```

I am trying to add an enrichment step (and call a Lambda function) in the pipe in order to convert the Protobuf message into JSON and allow the Step Function to edit it further. So the Pipe looks like this:

[image: Pipe components diagram]

In the lambda (built with Quarkus) I'm trying to convert the String value to the Protobuf model but I'm unable to. So far I've tried:

`parseFrom` with `ByteBuffer`:

```java
ByteBuffer wrap = ByteBuffer.wrap(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
return MyEventProto.MyEvent.parseFrom(wrap);

// Error: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: 
//   Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.
```

`parseDelimitedFrom` with bytes from value:

```java
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
return MyEventProto.MyEvent.parseDelimitedFrom(inputStream);

// Error: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: 
//   While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  
//   This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported 
//   its own length.
```

`parseDelimitedFrom`/`parseFrom` with Base64 decode of value `InputSteam`:

```java
byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
return MyEventProto.MyEvent.parseDelimitedFrom(new ByteArrayInputStream(decode));
// or return MyEventProto.MyEvent.parseFrom(new ByteArrayInputStream(decode));

// No error but it's returning an empty object back,
// similar to what MyEventProto.MyEvent.getDefaultInstance() returns
```

`parseFrom` with Base64 decode of value in raw bytes:

```java
byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
return MyEventProto.MyEvent.parseFrom(decode);

// Error: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: 
//   Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
```

Is there a way to parse the protobuf message?

### EDIT 1:

In the docs I figured that AWS passes in the Base64 encoded message. So I used this approach:

```java
byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(value.getBytes());
ByteBuffer wrap = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
return MyEventProto.MyEvent.parseFrom(wrap);
```

But then started using https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app to see if I can decode the message and started removing bytes from the start. So removing the first few bytes (`AAAAFVwA`) and the padding (`==`) worked! Still can't figure out what AWS adds in the beginning of that message and renders it impossible to parse directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Kafka adds some extra bytes in the message, probably to allow the deserializers to parse the message without issues. In my edit above, manually removing that extra bytes allowed me to parse the message without using a deserializer.

For a proper solution, first construct a `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufDeserializer`:

```java
String schemaRegistryUrl = "http://schema.registry:port";
Map<String, Object> protoDeserialiserProperties = Map.of(
    KafkaProtobufDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl,
    KafkaProtobufDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_PROTOBUF_VALUE_TYPE, Message.class,
    KafkaProtobufDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_PROTOBUF_KEY_TYPE, String.class
);

SchemaRegistryClient registryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryUrl, 10, List.of(new ProtobufSchemaProvider()), Collections.emptyMap());

KafkaProtobufDeserializer<Message> deserializer = new KafkaProtobufDeserializer<>(registryClient, protoDeserialiserProperties);
```

using:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-protobuf-serializer</artifactId>
  <version>${latest.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And then parse the message:

```java
byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(value.getBytes());
Message deserialized = deserializer.deserialize("my-topic", bytes);

MyEventProto.MyEvent offersByEvent = MyEventProto.MyEvent.parseFrom(deserialized.toByteString());
```